# Change xml value programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml

For example, I have this code:

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke 
            android:width="1dip" 
            android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

How can I change the value of `android:color`?

Thanks

Comment: inside the xml? It is impossibile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it in runtime, then change it whenever you want:

```
RoundRectShape rect = new RoundRectShape(
  new float[] {30,30, 30,30, 30,30, 30,30},
  null,
  null);
ShapeDrawable bg = new ShapeDrawable(rect);
bg.getPaint.setColor(0x99FFFFFF);
view.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
```

Comment: Ok working fine, but it only changes background color and I want to change stroke color. How to do that??

Comment: Read this tutorial: http://www.betaful.com/2012/01/programmatic-shapes-in-android/